# Use Grunt task variables in config

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to define variables in the config of my Grunt task, which are being replaced by my task.

My use-case is that I'm trying to create separate JS output files, based on a config.json which contains configurations for multiple sites.

An example of my config:

```
extractProjectConfigs: {
  options: {
    merge: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/extracted.js',
    configWrapper: 'window.config = {{ extractedConfig }};'
  },
  prod: {
    src: ['./config/*.json'],
    dest: '.tmp/scripts/{{ configKey }}/searchbox.js'
  }
}
```

In my `extractProjectConfigs` task, I define the variables `configKey` and `extractedConfig` and I'd like the values of both to be in my config.

How can I achieve this? I already tried including Grunt Templates in my config definition (i.e. `<%= extractedConfig %>` or `<%= configKey %>`), but since Grunt Template parses variables before passing them to my task, it basically means my variables turn into empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out Grunt Templates were the right way to go. Grunt Templates parse variables defined by `<%= %>` before passing them to the task. However, Grunt Templates also offer a way to determine your own variable delimiter, which allows you to use Grunt Templates in your task that are parsed after the task ran, meaning I can use variables in my config.

I ended up using the following config:

```
extractProjectConfigs: {
  options: {
    merge: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/extracted.js',
    configWrapper: 'window.config = {{= extractedConfig }};'
  },
  prod: {
    src: ['./config/*.json'],
    dest: '.tmp/scripts/{{= configKey }}/searchbox.js'
  }
}
```

In my task, I used the following custom Grunt template function to parse the config:

```
function parseTemplate(template, vars) {
  grunt.template.addDelimiters('double-brackets', '{{', '}}');

  return grunt.template.process(template, {
    data: vars,
    delimiters: 'double-brackets'
  });
}
```

This function can then be used within the task, for instance as follows:

```
var dest = parseTemplate(file.dest, {
  projectKey: 'foo'
});
```

This can then be used within `grunt.file.write`: `grunt.file.write(dest, 'write something to dest with projectKey replaced by foo');`

Comment: Can you please approve your answer?

Comment: @wrager thanks for your comment. This is an old thread, so I updated both the original question and the answer a bit to make it more clear (took me a while to understand the exact problem here). Can you verify whether this explanation looks clear to you?

Comment: Even in the original version, your answer was quite understandable. Thanks for taking the time :)